# Purge/reset all Redux data in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, react-redux, redux-devtools

I'm learning Redux and I somehow ended up with corrupted data. How do I purge all Redux data in Chrome browser?

There is nothing of value in my half developed app, so I don't need any precise manipulation, just a clean slate. But I don't want to clean other Chrome state like my history, passwords, and other stuff unrelated to this app.

I have installed Redux Devtools, but I can't find any edit functionality there. I've been searching for a while and all answers explain how to clean data from within the app. I don't want to write my own devtools in the app for this. This seems like a basic feature that should be included somewhere but I can't find it.